How to auto size all columns to fit the cell contents width in aggrid v32?
I was previously using aggrid v27 and to auto size the columns I used params.api.autoSizeAllColumns(); in onFirstDataRendered() function. After upgrading to v32, this is not working. In the migration guide it is mentioned that "Column API is now removed. API methods previously available via Column API are now available in Grid API instead". I tried locating the function and using it from gridApi but it doesn't seem to be working.
Expected: To autosize the columns to fit content width on load of aggrid in v32.

try gridApi function sizeColumnsToFit(), e.g. gridRef?.current?.api?.sizeColumnsToFit();

I want the horizontal scrolling which comes only when autoSizeAllColumns(); is used. I noticed another scenario. When I call gridRef?.current?.api?. autoSizeAllColumns() the grid auto sizes itself properly for the first time. If I go back and come to the same grid again, it does not autosize.

https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/6630 - same issue as mentioned here

To initially autosize your columns to fit the cell contents provide the grid option autoSizeStrategy with type = 'fitCellContents'.
You can read more about this in the AG Grid React documentation here
There is also an example in the documentation to use the gridApi to autosize columns if they have been resized which you might find useful.
